# Retrieving multiple variables in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried looking on several websites but I still don't understand how I could retrieve several GET variables using Express. I would like to be able to ping a Node.JS Express server url using:

```
file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:5012/variable1/variable2/variable3/variable4');
```

or

```
file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:5012/?1=variable1&2=variable2&3=variable3&4=variable4');
```

Then I need to be able to use them inside the Node.JS Express script in the form of variable1, variable2, variable3 and variable4 and not all in a single string. An object to store them in would be fine.

Thanks :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the second approach and use `GET` query parameters. [req.query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) will contain an object with the parsed query-string.

```
var express = require('express');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
  res.send('done');
});
```

You can also use [req.param(name)](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param) which will return the value if `name` is present in `req.params`, `req.body` or `req.query`